# android ffmpeg for multiple arch

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I'm building ffmpeg for android. It works fine with arm but fail with x86.

compilation is ok. But if I run the apk which use this x86 ffmpeg lib, logcat will print following errors:

`04-13 10:30:09.862: E/dalvikvm(1262): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.misgood.ipcamdemo-2/libplayer.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libavformat-55.so" needed by "libplayer.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libavformat-55.so" not found`

I'd checked apk file. All shared libraries are exist.

I guess the problem is the libraries is not config properly.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the script that I use to building ffmpeg for android arm and x86

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=$HOME/android-ndk-r9c

function build_core
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --disable-error-resilience \
    --disable-decoder=h263p \
    --disable-decoder=mpegvideo \
    --target-os=linux \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-std=c99 -O3 -fpic -DANDROID $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ARCH_SPEC \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make -j4
make install
}

function build_arm
{
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
ARCH_SPEC="--arch=arm \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
"
build_core
}

function build_x86
{
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-x86/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPU=x86
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-mincoming-stack-boundary=4 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -mstackrealign -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -m32"
ARCH_SPEC="--arch=x86 \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/i686-linux-android- \
    --cpu=i686
"
build_core
}

build_x86
```

Comment: It just build for x_86!!! even when I changed build_x86 to build_arm.